# PHP - bind_param with prepared not work with inner join

Tags: php, mysqli, bindparam

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['password'];
$playername = $_REQUEST['username'];

$req_player = "SELECT authme.realname,
                      authme.email,
                      authme.password,
                      luckperms_players.username,
                      luckperms_players.primary_group
               FROM authme 
                   INNER JOIN luckperms_players ON (authme.email = ?)
                   AND (luckperms_players.username = ?)";
    
if($player_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($req_player)){
    $player_stmt->bind_param("ss", $email,$playername);
    $player_stmt->execute();
    $player_stmt->bind_result($realname, $email, $password, $username, $primary_group);
    $player_stmt->fetch();

    if(password_verify($pass, $password)){
        $_SESSION['is_logged'] = true;
        $_SESSION['player_name'] = $realname;
        $_SESSION['group'] = $primary_group;
    }
```

As much as I put all the data correctly in the form, it throws me that the password is incorrect, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us how the password is stored. Also, make sure the column in your database for the password is able to hold a string long enough for the hash. Also, make sure that you are receving any data from the databse after your query.

Comment: Think that the `ON (authme.email = ?)` part should actually be a `WHERE` clause. (`INNER JOIN luckperms_players ON (luckperms_players.username = ?) WHERE (authme.email = ?)` )

Comment: The password is stored in a Minecraft server, in the same way that is not so important, since before trying without INNER JOIN, it worked correctly. The error started, when I tried to use INNER JOIN.

Comment: @AxelBenitez Then my bet is what Nigel said.

Comment: A join is used to link together 2 tables. It links a column in table 1 to a column in table 2. It is possible to also have an AND added to that relationship, but first you need the relationship

Comment: I tested the query directly in the SQL console and it worked perfectly, that means that the problem comes from something wrong in PHP.